# Eclipse visualization for chain of method call

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, visualization

I am looking for a useful eclipse plugin that can:

- visualize chain of methods call (Java)
- visualize data types hierarchy (Java)

Could you recommend anything?

Comment: Are you looking to get that information from source or for a running system's object (while debugging)?

Comment: What difference you want with Ctrl+Alt+H for call graph and F4 for type hierarchy?

Comment: CtrlAlt+H is that what helped me the most.

Comment: Note for future readers. We can now ask this sort of question on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

You could just also right click the method your interested in and click open call hierarchy or show references in the workspace project or working set. These are default with eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a tool called [Eclipse Diver](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/diver-dynamic-interactive-views-reverse-engineering)

It allows to reverse sequence diagram for any method, user manual [here](http://diver.sourceforge.net/docs/Diver.html)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at **Codemap**:
http://scg.unibe.ch/research/softwarecartography

--> Eclipse plugin which will show you a window with a 'map' of your code. It creates a map of islands displaying the classes in your project using a similartiy metric. It also allows you to display method calls as arrows between the 'islands'.

Very cool project, I am not up to date about the latest state of development.

Comment: The visualization is really cool but this is not what I am looking for. Anyway thanks for it.

Answer (score 1):

Not a released plugin, but for type hierarchy visualization have a look at http://pbwhiteboard.blogspot.com/2010/12/zest-type-hierarchy-view.html

For a related plugin (but not quite what you are looking for), have a look at http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/debug-visualisation-eclipse

Comment: The plugi debug-visualisation-eclipse looks poor. I need something like sequence diagram. So actually not in runtime. Some static code analysis can give such kind of information.

Comment: I have just discover more options for the tool - so that Open/Close. it can be used on every stack frame and connections between objects are nice visualized.

Answer (score 1):

[CallGraph Viewer Eclipse plug-in](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/callgraph-viewer):

Provides Call-Path and Sequence Diagram viewers.

Enables graphical analysis of program call relations and flow sequencing. Also enables exploration of extended class inheritance hierarchies.

Call-path analysis and class hieararchy resolution are performed
using the JDT platform Search and Call Hierarchy mechanisms.

Sequence diagrams are generated from a static analysis of
of the JDT platform AST for any selected class or method.

[image]